# Load credentials to an instance from a file

Tags: haskell, authentication, yesod

I want to use yesod-auth in a website I'm developing, but I don't want to just write my Google credentials in the file as it is public in GitHub. So I wrote some functions to parse the json file you get from google. the problem is that it get stuck in the IO monad and thus I cannot pass it the google oauth function. Does anyone has a solution for this?

```
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

clientId = (client_id . web . decode) <$> B.readFile "D:\\cred.json"
clientSecret = (client_secret . web . decode) <$> B.readFile "D:\\cred.json"
....
instance YesodAuth App
    authPlugins = [ authGoogleEmail clientId clientSecret ]
    ....
```

Comment: If you are using the Yesod scaffolding, you should use the existing mechanism defined there to achieve this.

Comment: I've looked on Hoogle and could not find such functions, Can you direct me to it? @Sibi

Comment: What I meant to say was that if you using the Yesod template for your web application ? You can create a scaffolding site if you follow the instructions here: https://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart . It is documented here: http://www.yesodweb.com/book/scaffolding-and-the-site-template